# Kafka-Streams keep input partitioning

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to know if there is a "good" way to write to the same partition (number) a message got consumed from with Kafka-streams. I have two Topics with the same amount of partitions and messages for individual users, where all messages for one user have to be in the same partition to avoid out of order messages for that user. The target partition has to be the same as the input-partition for out monitoring to work properly. 
I know that i have Access to the source Partition in a processor via the ProcessorContext if i use the processor-API. But in the StreamsPartitioner i only have the key, the value and the number of partitions. I could write a processor, that takes the input partition and writes it to the key since we don't use it ATM and it only contains null. But that feels really hacky since every record in one partition would have the same key and only works until we need the key to contain some real data. 
I could also parse the value and extract the id which is used to calculate the partition but that feels really bad aswell as it involves string parsing and seems unnecessary because i already have the partition one step before in the processor. 
 Is there a way keep partitioning unchanged for a stream in a way that does not involve parsing of the message i have serialised right before of the abuse of the key?

Comment: Why not create a UUID for the key to begin with?

Comment: I know that this per se would make sense but i don't have access to the producer writing to the first topic and i cannot see how this would help with my problem.

Comment: If you're outputting a null key, it'll be re-routed with the Default Partitioner. If you use a static value, such as a UUID or your own such ID field, then given the same number of partitions in the output topic, then the key will always be hashed and routed the same as the input topic... Now, if your producer actually overwrites the partitioner, then you would need to do so yourself or hard code that partition via forwarding in the processor

Comment: It seems that there is some userId in you data that is used to partition the input data -- if this userId is in your result data, you can apply the same partitioning strategy as you use upstream to preserve the partitioning.

Comment: Yes there is a UUID for each user present in the data but parsing the data again for partitioning seems wrong for me.
I always thought, that the of a message should identify the message and not the user it is associated with. 
But maybe that is the only way to do this at least some sort of non-abusive. Thank you

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I posted a similar question without realizing the ask here is quite similar. Do you think providing a signature in SinkNode which would possibly use context.partition for the forward calls instead of using stream partitioner might help. It will help in use cases where we dont have access to the original partitioner used by producer or we simply want to preserve the partitions without the need for reevaluating based on key/value etc. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Well, I guess this would be possible... Feel free to create a ticket and/or propose a KIP.

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasJ.Sax I opened a ticket and saw your comment about KIP. Atm i am waiting for access and will open one as soon as i get access

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.